# How can I handle control messages on the parent CDialog?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, window-messages

I've got some control like `CtrlTree` on `CMyDialog`.
I want to handle messages like `ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()` from `CTreeCtrl` in the `CMyDialog` class.

Is there any way in MFC to redirect message stream to parent?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The whole point of MFC's architecture is that it reflects messages from the parent to the control that generated the image in the first place, which promotes encapsulation, code reuse, and separation of responsibilities.

Comment: My employer gives me that task. Want to redirect message stream because handler on CDialog are already written. I understand that this solution is not agree with encapsulation. But if I wuld redirect message stream the project will be almost ready.

Have you got any ideas about this topic ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506145/how-to-handle-cedit-mouse-click-in-parent-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to redirect your messages is just sending a custom (`WM_USER + xxx`) message from your control's `ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN` handler to the parent class.

Place parent's `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` handler code in a separate method and call this method directly.

Something like that (pseudo code), presuming that your existing code sits in `HandleTreeCtrlLBDown()`

```
CMyTreeCtrl::OnLButtonDown(..)
{
   pParent ->SendMessage(WM_TREECTRLLBDOWN, 0, (LPARAM)this);
}

CControlParentDialog::OnTreeCtrlLBDown(wParam, lParam)
{
   HandleTreeCtrlLBDown();
}
```